# Swift: Fastest way to draw a rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I'm making a game that pretty much entirely consists of solid-colored rectangles. Currently, I'm using SKSpriteNodes for all of the rectangles in it, since they need to be animated and touched, but while creating a few hundred of them, I found them to cause a lot of lag.

All I need is a rectangle I can draw with a solid color, no textures or anything, but for some reason, these cause a lot of lag.

If possible, I want to avoid OpenGL as I tried it before and it took me months to do a single thing. I just feel like there must be a fast way that I can't find. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of profiling have you done to identify the source of the lag? What leads you to believe that it's specifically the time to draw the rectangles? Start with Instruments, and make sure you know where your time is going before you try switching technologies. More often the problem is layout or O(n^2) interaction between the entities rather than drawing. A few hundred rectangles isn't that many.

Comment: @RobNapier The only thing that leads me to think this is because that no posts I've found so far have actually used SKSpriteNodes to draw rectangles. I just feel like I should be doing something faster, since my entire game is based on rectangles.

Comment: The simplicity of your skin (i.e. just a rectangle rather than a more complex image) is unlikely the cause of your performance problems. Consider experiences like this one animating 10k particles: http://www.sdkboy.com/2014/01/10000-sprites-animating-and-no-loss-in-framerate-using-ios7s-spritekit/ Start with Instruments. That's how you find where your bottlenecks are. At these scales (100s), it is almost always an O(n^2) algorithm that has snuck into your system, not the act of drawing.

Comment: @RobNapier could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplicity of your skin (i.e. just a rectangle rather than a more complex image) is unlikely the cause of your performance problems. Consider experiences like [this one animating 10k particles](http://www.sdkboy.com/2014/01/10000-sprites-animating-and-no-loss-in-framerate-using-ios7s-spritekit/). Start with Instruments. That's how you find where your bottlenecks are. At these scales (100s), it is almost always an O(n^2) algorithm that has snuck into your system, not the act of drawing.